# Google Benchmark while vs for

Tags: c++

I'm uncertain how to use Google Benchmark correctly.

The example in the [GitHub-Documentation](https://github.com/google/benchmark) states to use the following syntax:

```
for( auto _ : state)
{
  // code to be benchmarked
}
```

But most [examples](http://www.bfilipek.com/2016/05/google-benchmark-library.html) in the internet show the follwoing syntax:

```
while( state.KeepRunning() )
{
  // code to be benchmarked
}
```

I used both methods to compare them and they show slightly different measurments.

Any advice?

Comment: Do they do the same thing? The range loop appears to traverse through something whereas the while loop seems to keep calling a function (which probably does an increment/decrement within it)

Comment: @Yashas I feel like you just restated OPs question using different words.

Comment: They would show different measurements, since the range based-for incurs a *slight* overhead. Not likely to be anything significant. Use whichever you like best.

Comment: @StoryTeller the pull request that adds the ranged for argues that it is more efficient.

Comment: @user2079303 - I'd love to see those measurements. Adding a range based for support means adhering to the iteration protocol. That may or may not be cost-less. But *more efficient*?

Comment: @StoryTeller there are no measurements, but author argues that it is easier to optimize: *"This formulation is much more efficient, because the variable counting
the loop index is stored in the iterator produced by State::begin(),
which itself is stored in function-local memory and therefore not accessible
by code outside of the function. Therefore the compiler knows the iterator
hasn't been changed every iteration."*

Comment: @user2079303 - If they say so

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But most examples in the internet show the follwoing syntax:

This is because most examples have been written in the past, and the alternative ranged-for syntax is a quite new feature: https://github.com/google/benchmark/pull/454 (about 2 months).

> I used both methods to compare them and they show slightly different measurments.
>
> Any advice?

They are two alternative ways to do the same thing. Consider whether *slightly* different measurement is significant. If not, then it won't matter which you use. If it is significant, then you can conclude that the benchmarked code is very efficient. Use the one that produces consistently lower measurements, since that loop has smaller overhead.